# Text Mesh Pro texts do not appear in apk

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor, unity-ui

While Text Mesh Pro, which I use in my Unity program, appears on the [Editor Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxYut.png) without any problems, when I build the apk and open it on my [Android Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0Sit.png), the texts do not appear. [Editor Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxYut.png)
[Android Device Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0Sit.png)

Comment: Does the text show up in the [Unity Device Simulator](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/device-simulator.html)??

Comment: Do you have the editor resolution set to the same as the target platform?  Might be incorrect' anchoring.

Comment: yes, and text show up in my virtual device in the pc too.